# Retrofit Android JSON Parsing With RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I recently learnt a bit about json parsing with retrofit2. I tried implementing on my own but no output is shown and no errors either in the log cat. What could be wrong? Take a look at my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RestClient restClient;
private List<Movies> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
private MoviesAdapter adapter;

private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

private static final String API_KEY = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    if (API_KEY.isEmpty()){
        Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Access Requires an API Key", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, moviesList, R.layout.movie_items_layout);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    restClient = new RestClient();
    RestEndpoint restService = restClient.getMoviesClient().create(RestEndpoint.class);
    Call<MoviesResponse> moviesResponseCall = restService.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);
    moviesResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {

            moviesList.clear();
            moviesList.addAll(response.body().getMoviesResult());
            List<Movies> list = response.body().getMoviesResult();
            for (Movies movies : list){
                Movies movies1 = new Movies(movies.isAdult(), movies.getOverview(), movies.getReleaseDate(),
                        movies.getTitle(), movies.getBackdropPath(), movies.getVoteAverage());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //moviesList = response.body().getMoviesResult();

            Log.v(TAG, "Number of Movies Received:" + moviesList.size());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Movies data model class is shown  below:

```
public class Movies {

@SerializedName("poster_path")
private String posterPath;

@SerializedName("adult")
private boolean adult;

@SerializedName("overview")
private String overview;

@SerializedName("release_date")
private String releaseDate;

@SerializedName("genre_ids")
private List<Integer> genreIds;

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("original_title")
private String originalTitle;

@SerializedName("original_language")
private String originalLanguage;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
private String backdropPath;

@SerializedName("popularity")
private double popularity;

@SerializedName("vote_count")
private String voteCount;

@SerializedName("video")
private boolean video;

@SerializedName("vote_average")
private double voteAverage;

public Movies(boolean adult, String overview, String releaseDate, String title, String backdropPath, double voteAverage) {
    this.adult = adult;
    this.overview = overview;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.title = title;
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}

public Movies() {
}

public boolean isAdult() {
    return adult;
}

public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
    this.adult = adult;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBackdropPath() {
    return backdropPath;
}

public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}

public double getVoteAverage() {
    return voteAverage;
}

public void setVoteAverage(double voteAverage) {
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}
```

}

Also take a look at my recyclerview adapter class:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Movies> moviesList;
private int rowLayout;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movies> moviesList, int rowLayout) {
    this.context = context;
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
}

@Override
public MoviesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new MoviesHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesHolder holder, int position) {
    Movies movies = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movies.getTitle());
    holder.date.setText(movies.getReleaseDate());
    holder.desription.setText(movies.getOverview());
    holder.rating.setText(String.valueOf(movies.getVoteAverage()));

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(movies.getBackdropPath())
            .into(holder.backdrop);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    return moviesList.size();
}
```

}

The json data was fetched from themoviedb website with an api key. Kindly point out what's wrong.

Comment: Unrelated, but you do not need `List<Movies> list = response.body().getMoviesResult()` and the loop after that

Comment: Ok, thanks.I can see in my logcat that the response is coming, but how do I display the received response inside the recyclerview.

Comment: You need to add more information to this question. Have you checked the size of the list from the response body? If data is being returned, ensure your adapter is receiving it into its data set.

Comment: Yes, I used logging and the size of the list is displayed in log cat but the adapter is not receiving the data set.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    return moviesList.size();
}
```

You are creating new list , which size is 0, so your adapter always thinks there are no elememnts

Just try removing `moviesList = new ArrayList<>();`