# i want show all of my data in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Maybe my question is a beginner one
i have this JSON , as a response , I post a "id" and the result is like that , as u can see my response began with square brackets [] and i can't change it

```
[{
    "id": "1111",
    "nam": "name",
    "namk": "surename",
    "lygn": [{
                "id": "3003",
                "mas": "lurem11",               
                "yeg": "lurem11"
            },
            {
                "id": "5121",
                "mas": "lurem",
                "yeg": "lurem"
            }],
    "lisar": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "sharh": "lurem22",
            "amal": "lurem22",
            "toz": "1",
            "tb": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2113",
            "sharh": "0",
            "amal": "lurem",
            "toz",
            "tb": "1965/06/11"
        }
    ]
}]
```

this is my request :

```
@POST("isargaran")
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    Call<List<ForAll>> postbyid(@Body ForAll md);
```

and my model class is :

```
public class ForAll {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("nam")
    @Expose
    private String nam;
    @SerializedName("namk")
    @Expose
    private String namk;
    @SerializedName("namp")
    @Expose
    private String namp;
   
    @SerializedName("lygn")
    @Expose
    public List<Ygn> ygn = null;

    @SerializedName("lisar")
    @Expose
    public List<lisar> lisar;

  //getter and setter 

}
```

and i have "lisar" and "Ygn" class too , So far there is no problem because I get the Response.body and everything well ( i used all of my getters and i showed then in textview ) but the thing is i wanna show them in a recyclerview , i tried and i could only see index 0 , can't see all of them , i mean i can only see (lygn)

```
{
                "id": "3003",
                "mas": "lurem",               
                "yeg": "lurem"
            }
```

(and first data for "lisar")

and i don't want to share my adapter And make it crowded here , my question is , HOW CAN I SHOW ALL OFF MY "lygn" AND "lisar" IN RECYCLERVIEW(i have a recycler for each)
thanks you guys , ples help me

** i think problem is because of my response starts with []

Comment: how are you parsing your response json?

Comment: @sneharc ```ForAll result = forAlls.get(position);```
... 
```result.getLisar().get(position).getTb()```
 in my adapter

sorry if i got you wrong ma'am

Comment: check the adapter class from these links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36967003/9752602  https://stackoverflow.com/q/41402581/9752602

Comment: @sneharc
It could not help me
I have other recyclers in my app that show all the data (exactly what I want , i mean i know how can i use adapter for simple jsons like those jsons in those links)
but my problem is with these lists ("lygn" and "lisar")"

thank you anyways  

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to separate response

```
ForAll resource = response.get(0);
```

Now you need to pass separate data in recycler view Adapter

```
List<Ygn> lygnData = resource.getygn();
List<lisar> lisarData = resource.getlisar();
```

Comment: i appricate that but i still have one data , can't show all of them

Comment: can you share with me your adapter class? so I am giving you a solution fast.

Comment: which array size set in adapter?
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

Comment: i did that i return modelArrayList.size(); but i only have index 0

Answer (score -1):

setup adapter with recyclerview like this,

```
//Pass your list in to adapter   
var adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(list)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
recyclerView.adapter = pendingAdapter
```

Here is your adapater class,

```
 class RecyclerViewAdapter(
        private val list: List<String>
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)   // pass your row (.xml) Here
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            // Bind Your Data Here
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    }
```